# Excel Macro to fill a column with activex textboxes

Tags: excel, vba

I would to like fill the range E1:E10 with activex textboxes (which fit perfectly over the cells), and which would resize if cells were resized.

I am getting an 'application or object defined error'.

```
sub pastetextboxes()
For i=1 to 10
  set rng=activesheet.cells(i,5)
  set test=activesheet.oleobjects.add(classtype:="Forms.textbox.1", Link:=false, Displayasicon:=false, Left:=rng.left, top:=rng.top, width:=rng.width,height:=rng.height)
next i

end sub
```

Comment: Well you have used a `;` after width and none after height. Put a `:` and it will put in your textboxes. Either way, this won't autofit these textboxes.

Comment: @jvdv sorry that's just a typo. Its not working for some other reason

Comment: It works fine in my test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind to forget the ActiveX controls then:

```
Sub pastetextboxes()

For i = 1 To 10
    With ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5)
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox msoTextOrientationHorizontal, .Left, .Top, .Width, .Height
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

These shapes will change in size when you fiddle around with column width or row height.

If you want ActiveX controls you can do it like so:

```
Sub pastetextboxes()

For i = 1 To 10
    With ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5)
        Set test = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(classtype:="Forms.textbox.1", Link:=False, Displayasicon:=False, Left:=.Left, Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, Height:=.Height)
        test.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

I hope you won't struggle with the fontsize bug using ActiveX controls.

Comment: thanks but it needs to be activex. Can I not set auto-resize with that?

Comment: thanks but it needs to be activex. Can I not set auto-resize with that?